# Different layoutparams for different views

Tags: android

Is it possible to set one LayoutParams to RelativeLayout(it is inside another Layout) and set another ones to a view that is in this Layout.

RelativeLayout inside which another Relative Layout with some LayoutParams and inside 2nd Reltive layout a view with another LayoutParams

Is situation like possible?

Comment: You question is a bit unclear. You should proofread and rephrase your question for clarity and provide some code or layout example that illustrates what you're trying to achieve. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your question is not clear. All `View`s that are inside other `ViewGroup`s have `LayoutParams`, and they're rarely the same as another's.

Comment: @mike-m Thank you. So, can I add some rules to the view which is inside relativeLayout?

Comment: Sure. Those rules will only affect how it is laid out in its direct parent, though. The grandparent won't know or care about that innermost `View`. It lays out its children per their `LayoutParams`, then each of its children will lay out their children, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

try by,

1.giving id to each views you wanna resize

2.initialising those ids to a member variable

3.setting the layoutparams using setLayoutParams(left,top,right,bottom) method.